# Update JProgressBar Without Knowing Progress

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I want to use a JProgressBar but I don't have any measurement of progress for how long the task will take to complete. The idea is to have a progress bar displaying the status of a shutdown process but I don't know how long it takes, and I have no way of editing the class that does the shutdown process.

Is there a way to use a JProgressBar without having any indication of the progress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `setIndeterminate(true)`.

From the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html):

> To indicate that a task of unknown length is executing, you can put a
>   progress bar into indeterminate mode. While the bar is in
>   indeterminate mode, it animates constantly to show that work is
>   occurring. As soon as you can determine the task's length and amount
>   of progress, you should update the progress bar's value and switch it
>   back to determinate mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `JProgressBar` which displays in indeterminate mode, as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29). The default animation is a 'bouncer,' that is, the progress indicator will go back and forth between the two ends of the bar until you stop it.